# Kendo UI Autocomplete Data Source issue

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have several auto completes all set up and working using the same datasource defined as a variable. However I am not sure how to get my groups autocomplete to work as this has the potential to have multiple values.

Here is my datasource:

```
UsersDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/_layouts/handlers/Users.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "get",
            cache: false
        }
    }
});
```

A sample of this json is shown below (note the groups):

```
[{"Id":"USERNAME","Type":"External","Name":"Jim Jones","Email":"jjones@email.com","Address":"1600 Penn Ave","Organization":"Company ABC","Notes":"User Notes","Groups":["Group A","Group B","Group C","Group D"]}]
```

All of the other autocompletes I have set up work fine with this code:

```
$("#SearchAddress").kendoAutoComplete({
    placeholder: "Address",
    dataTextField: "Address",
    dataValueField: "Address",
    dataSource: UsersDataSource
});
```

I am not really sure how to make this work for the groups...  Any advice would be appreciated.

**Edit: I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nlarkin/mjD5H/) to illustrate this issue**

**Edit: Fiddle updated again**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that the second autocomplete is bound to the `Groups` field of the `peoples` array:

```
$("#SearchGroup").kendoAutoComplete({
    placeholder: "Group",
    dataSource: {
        data: peoples[0].Groups,
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pSMtt/4/​

Here is how to get all groups:

```
var groups = [];

for (var i = 0; i < peoples.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < peoples[i].Groups.length; j++) {
       groups.push(peoples[i].Groups[j]);
    }
}

$("#SearchGroup").kendoAutoComplete({
    placeholder: "Group",
    dataSource: {
        data: groups,
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific in the fiddle. This situation only works for the first set of groups, and not if there are different groups per each people[0], people[1]... Here is an updated fiddle....http://jsfiddle.net/nlarkin/mjD5H/

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? You probably need to update the second autocomplete data source. Use the change event of the first autocomplete and the data method of the data source of the second autocomplete.

Comment: I want to get a drop down list of all groups for all people, no association with any other fields.

Comment: Then you need to create an array which contains all groups for all people.